# Hadoop Streaming job failing

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run my first mapreduce job, which aggregates some data from xml files. My job is failing, and as I am a newbie at Hadoop, I would appreciate if someone could please take a look at what is going wrong.

I have:

posts_mapper.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

input_string = sys.stdin.read()


class User(object):

        def __init__(self, id):
                self.id = id
                self.post_type_1_count = 0
                self.post_type_2_count = 0
                self.aggregate_post_score = 0
                self.aggregate_post_size = 0
                self.tags_count = {}


users = {}
root = ET.fromstring(input_string)
for child in root.getchildren():
        user_id = int(child.get("OwnerUserId"))
        post_type = int(child.get("PostTypeId"))
        score = int(child.get("Score"))
        #view_count = int(child.get("ViewCount"))
        post_size = len(child.get("Body"))
        tags = child.get("Tags")

        if user_id not in users:
                users[user_id] =  User(user_id)
        user = users[user_id]
        if post_type == 1:
                user.post_type_1_count += 1
        else:
                user.post_type_2_count += 1
        user.aggregate_post_score += score
        user.aggregate_post_size += post_size

        if tags != None:
                tags = tags.replace("<", " ").replace(">", " ").split()
                for tag in tags:
                        if tag not in user.tags_count:
                                user.tags_count[tag] = 0
                        user.tags_count[tag] += 1

for i in users:
        user = users[i]
        out = "%d %d %d %d %d " % (user.id, user.post_type_1_count, user.post_type_2_count, user.aggregate_post_score, user.aggregate_post_size)
        for tag in user.tags_count:
                out += "%s %d " % (tag, user.tags_count[tag])
        print out
```

posts_reducer.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


class User(object):

        def __init__(self, id):
                self.id = id
                self.post_type_1_count = 0
                self.post_type_2_count = 0
                self.aggregate_post_score = 0
                self.aggregate_post_size = 0
                self.tags_count = {}

users = {}
for line in sys.stdin:

        vals = line.split()
        user_id = int(vals[0])
        post_type_1 = int(vals[1])
        post_type_2 = int(vals[2])
        aggregate_post_score = int(vals[3])
        aggregate_post_size = int(vals[4])
        tags = {}
        if len(vals) > 5:
                #this means we got tags
                for i in range (5, len(vals), 2):
                        tag = vals[i]
                        count = int((vals[i+1]))
                        tags[tag] = count

        if user_id not in users:
                users[user_id] = User(user_id)
        user = users[user_id]
        user.post_type_1_count += post_type_1
        user.post_type_2_count += post_type_2
        user.aggregate_post_score += aggregate_post_score
        user.aggregate_post_size += aggregate_post_size
        for tag in tags:
                if tag not in user.tags_count:
                        user.tags_count[tag] = 0
                user.tags_count[tag] += tags[tag]

for i in users:
        user = users[i]
        out = "%d %d %d %d %d " % (user.id, user.post_type_1_count, user.post_type_2_count, user.aggregate_post_score, user.aggregate_post_size)
        for tag in user.tags_count:
                out += "%s %d " % (tag, user.tags_count[tag])
        print out
```

I run the command:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -input /stackexchange/beer/posts -output /stackexchange/beer/results -mapper posts_mapper.py -reducer posts_reducer.py -file ~/mapreduce/posts_mapper.py -file ~/mapreduce/posts_reducer.py
```

and get the output:

packageJobJar: [/home/hduser/mapreduce/posts_mapper.py, /home/hduser/mapreduce/posts_reducer.py, /tmp/hadoop-unjar6585010774815976682/] [] /tmp/streamjob8863638738687983603.jar tmpDir=null
15/03/20 10:18:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at Master/10.1.1.22:8040
15/03/20 10:18:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at Master/10.1.1.22:8040
15/03/20 10:18:57 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
15/03/20 10:18:57 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
15/03/20 10:18:57 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1426769192808_0004
15/03/20 10:18:58 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1426769192808_0004
15/03/20 10:18:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://i-644dd931:8088/proxy/application_1426769192808_0004/
15/03/20 10:18:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1426769192808_0004
15/03/20 10:19:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1426769192808_0004 running in uber mode : false
15/03/20 10:19:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:19:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:19:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000007_0, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:19:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000008_0, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:19:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000009_0, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000006_1, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 7% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000007_1, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 10% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000008_1, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 10% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000009_1, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000006_2, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

15/03/20 10:20:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000007_2, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 17%
15/03/20 10:20:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000008_2, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426769192808_0004_m_000009_2, Status : FAILED
15/03/20 10:20:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 0%
15/03/20 10:20:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/03/20 10:20:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1426769192808_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1426769192808_0004_m_000006
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hadoop does not show `stderr` for your python mapper/reducer so this output does not give any clue.

I would recommend you the following 2 throubleshooting steps:

1. Test your mapper/reducer locally:

`cat {your_input_files} | ./posts_mapper.py | sort | ./posts_reducer.py`

2. If you did not find any issue on step1, create the map reduce job and check the output logs:

`yarn logs -applicationId application_1426769192808_0004`

or

`hdfs dfs -cat /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/{user}/logs/`